# Brush for detailed staining

Tags: painting, tools, staining

What kind of brush should I use for some detailed staining? I currently have a 1" Purdy wedge but I need smaller than that. Is regular hair brush okay or sponge, flat or angled etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "detailed staining"?  Usual practice with stain is flood on, let it be absorbed into the wood and settle into the grain or carvings, wipe off excess, let dry.

Comment: doing edges and hard to reach spots

Comment: Honestly I just grab an "acid brush" which is a cheapie maybe 1/2" wide.